# Problem with creating AlertDialg in webview (RNCWebViewManager)

Tags: android, react-native, android-alertdialog

I am trying to make `AlertDialog` for user if there is SSL cerificate error in my android app which uses webview. I am using react native.

In my file `RNCWebViewManger.java` there is function called `onReceivedSslError` in which I am trying to diplay alert dialog to ask user whether to continue or not. This is my code

```
 @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView webView, final SslErrorHandler handler, final SslError error) {


      //handler.proceed();
       //handler.cancel();
      final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setMessage("notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid");
      builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          handler.proceed();
        }
      });
      builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          handler.cancel();
        }
      });
      final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.show();
}
```

But I have some difficulites with creating AlertDialg in part `final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` where I have error

> incompatible types: RNCWebViewClient cannot be converted to Context

Please how to solve this?

I am pretty new to react native and android

Comment: anyone to help?

Answer (score 0):

try this `final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: I really don't know what is happening but when I try your answer I get error: cannot find symbol variable getApplicationContext

Comment: @HardRock i'm sorry , I was mean `getApplicationContext()` I will replace it